# Finding $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (f(k)g(k))$ (calculus of finite difference)

Tags: calculus

So, I'm working though Smoryński's *Logical Number Theory* and I'm stuck on the following exercise. Define $\Delta f(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$. Given this, it's not difficult to show that $\Delta (f(x) g(x)) = \Delta f(x) g(x+1) + f(x) \Delta g(x)$. Smoryński then asks us to prove, using this result, that

> $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n f(k)g(k) = g(n)(\sum\limits_{k=0}^n f(k)) - \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} [\Delta g(k) (\sum\limits_{i=0}^n f(i))]$

I'm a little bit at loss about how to proceed, though. I imagine that somewhere I'll have to use the fact that $\sum\limits_{i=a}^b f(i) = \Delta^{-1} f(x)|^{b+1}_a$, but I can't quite see how to pull it off. Any hints?

Comment: did you try induction?

Comment: @user72012 - No. But it seems (correct me if I'm wrong) that, in order to prove the base step, I'd already have to have proved the desired result.

Comment: The base step, $n=1$, is just confirming $f(1)g(1) + f(0)g(0) = g(1) [f(0) + f(1)] - [g(1)-g(0)][f(0)+f(1)]$ which is false.

Comment: @Winther - He calls it the "summation by parts" exercise, but he gives the formula in my question (unless I'm missing something or read something wrong). Here's a link:
https://books.google.com.br/books?id=ycH3CAAAQBAJ&pg=PP4&dq=Smorynski+logical+number+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OS-YVf_WGoemgwSwgILoDQ&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=summation%20by%20parts&f=false

Comment: @Masacroso - You mean $\Delta \sum\limits^b_{i=a}f(i) = \sum\limits^b_{i=a} \Delta f(i) = f(x)|^{b+1}_a$?

Comment: Forget what I said @Nagase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't find your result. Here is my derivation of a close result :

First step : get out the first part of the RHS

$$\sum_{k=0}^n f(k)g(k) = g(n)\sum_{k=0}^n f(k) - g(n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k)g(k)$$

$$ = g(n)\sum_{k=0}^n f(k) -  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(k)(g(n)-g(k))$$

Now notice that

$$g(n)-g(k) = \sum_{i=k}^{n-1} \Delta g(i)$$

You get then

$$ = g(n)\sum_{k=0}^n f(k) -  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sum_{i=k}^{n-1} \Delta g(i) f(k)$$

Then you invert the order of summation :

$$ = g(n)\sum_{k=0}^n f(k) -   \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \Delta g(i) \sum_{k=0}^{i}f(k) $$

The difference with your result is that the sum of the f(k) on the right is only up to i, and not to n-1

Comment: Hmm. Weird, maybe the formulation in Smoryński's book is wrong? And, by the way, you got the first equation by simply using distributive properties, right?

Comment: The formulation in Smoryński's book is wrong (a typo). Just write out the case $n=1$ to see this.

Comment: @Winther - Sorry, I got a bit confused, the last formula of the exercise or the last formula of Tryss's answer?

Comment: @Nagase It's just a simple typo in the last equation here. It should be $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\Delta g(i) \sum_{k=0}^i f(k)$ .

Comment: Oh yes, I made a typo in the last equation, thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @Winther: Or, to stay closer to the original, $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\Delta g(k)\sum_{i=0}^kf(i)$. Note that there’s already an obvious typo in the problem, an extra right parenthesis in the first term on the righthand side, so we know that typos are possible.

Comment: @Winther - Right, thanks.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Very nice, so the typo in the book is simply a one letter typo: a '$n$' where it should be a '$k$' in the last sum. Thats a very easy mistake to make.